# How to expand menu in IntelliJ without using right arrow

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

I am currently using IDEAVim on intelliJ on a 60% keyboard without arrow keys.
I am looking for a way to expand the menu of "Show Intentions Action"(the menu which you get from hitting  + ) to the right without having to use the  arrow key.

If i just hit enter, it will select and execute the intention instead of giving me a menu to "Suppress" or "Ignore" the intention

Answer (score 3):

You [cannot remap any cursor keys](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108609) for the menu actions in IntelliJ IDEA.

The only workaround I can see if to use some system application to remap the keys depending on the OS you are using. For example, on Windows one can map some keys combination to produce the arrow key code with AutoHotkey or a macro in the third-party keyboard driver settings.

Anything that will produce the same code as the real right arrow key on your system should work.